# RAID Level - minimum number of drives for RAID 10

Tags: raid

I tried a sizing tool for my database and i got the following recommendations:

```
[2x RAID 1/0 drives for Installation (I)]
[2x RAID 1/0 drives for Transaction Log (L)]
[2x RAID 1/0 drives for TempDB (TD)]
[2x RAID 1/0 drives for Database (D)]
```

I saw the web that minimum number of drives needed for RAID 10 is 4 and i am wondering why 2 drives are enough by the recommendation? 
Also, what is installation used for? 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I saw the web that minimum number of drives needed for RAID 10 is 4 and i am wondering why 2 drives are enough by the recommendation?

It most likely means RAID 1.

> Also, what is installation used for?

Where you install the OS and/or database application.

Answer (score 0):

In this context RAID 1+0 and RAID 1 are the same thing. Basically, the advice you've been given is to separate spindles and have small RAID groups to cater to each function.